# How to change the resolution(DPI) of signature

Tags: codenameone

1. I'm using     getsignature().scaledSmallerRatio(300,100), I want to change the resolution to  96 DPI. How can I do that?
2. 300 and 100 are the width and height in what dimensions?

Please advise

Comment: DPI isn't a resolution. It's dots per inch. 96 DPI means you will have 96 pixels on a single inch of the screen. The DPI per device is determined at the factory based on the number of pixels in an inch of your screen. Check out [this developer guide section on density](https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html#_density).

Comment: how can change the resolution of the image and 300, 100 signifies the ratio of which dimensions?  What is the smallerRatio vs largerRatio difference?

Comment: You can use the `scaledSmallerRatio` as you have. Scaling while maintaining aspect ratio will only use one of the arguments and fit the image within the boundaries to avoid squishing the image. That call you wrote meant the image won't be larger than 300px wide or 100px high. If you pick the larger ratio it will mean that the image will have either width of 300 or height of 100 but the other side might be slightly larger.